# Regex-python: Match a string in alphabetical order

Tags: python, regex

I've come across a problem that asks to match a string with lowercase characters in alphabetical order, including any number of spaces. The regex should match strings like: `"abc"`,`"  aaabbvv   "`, `"uv xyz"`, or`" acg jko pr"`but it shouldn't match strings like: `""`, `"abzc"`, `"zabc"`, `"x  v c"` because the characters are not in alphabetical order and the first one is empty. So, I tried to solve it but couldn't figure out how to check the order of the characters in the string. Here's my solution so far,
**regex =`'^(\s*[a-z]+\s*)*$`** (it fails with strings that aren't in alphabetical order). Could someone help, please? Or at least give me a hint. Thanks A LOT.

Comment: I wrote an answer in the question I marked this a duplicate of, you can use `(?:a+\s*(?(?![b-z])(*ACCEPT))` in each option (I added `\s*` and changed `b` to `[b-z]`), but I would urge you to not use regex at all; it would be like using a hammer to remove a screw from a motherboard: not the right tool for the job, albeit possible.

Comment: @ctwheels I don't think that question is a duplicate. In that question, the OP is looking for a string of characters in order without any characters (in the alphabet) being skipped. If I'm understanding correctly, in this question, some characters can be skipped. The only requirement is that the characters in the string must be arranged in alphabetical order. In fact, the answers provided in that question would fail to provide the output desired here. That said, some of the techniques in that question could probably be adapted to work here.

Comment: @Waylan I guess you're right since [this](https://regex101.com/r/RxR4Va/11) works too `^(?=.*[a-z])a*\s*b*\s*c*\s*d*\s*e*\s*f*\s*g*\s*h*\s*i*\s*j*\s*k*\s*l*\s*m*\s*n*\s*o*\s*p*\s*q*\s*r*\s*s*\s*t*\s*u*\s*v*\s*w*\s*x*\s*y*\s*z*\s*$`.

Comment: @ctwheels oh, wow! This solution really helps. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: @Hajar you can also generate it [this way](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQz1Ow942plgrOlG3KlYTyFBX0FYoUtcCsfSy8jPzNHIyi0s0chMLNJIzinQUihLz0lM1LM11FAyNjDWBAKhcCaRaRUnz/38A): `print('^(?=\s*[a-z])\s*' + r'*\s*'.join(list(map(chr, range(97, 123)))) + "*\s*$")`